# How to prove that if $\gcd(x,n)=1$, then there is a positive integer $m<n$ such that $n\mid x^m-1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $x$ and $n$ be integers, such that $\gcd(x,n)=1$. How do I prove that there is a positive integer $m<n$, such that $n\mid x^m-1$?

I'm supposed to prove this using Pigeonhole Principle, and I tried factoring $x^m-1$ and using Diophantine Equation, but I still didn't see how I could apply Pigeonhole here. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Such $m$ is given by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: To use PP, consider the map $m\mapsto x^m\bmod n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(n+1)$ elements $\{1, x, x^2, \cdots, x^n\}$ can not each be in a separate congruency class, $\pmod{n}$, because there are only $(n)$ such classes.  Furthermore, none of these elements can be congruent to $0 \pmod{n}.$

Therefore, ...

Comment: well but we have to be careful here, and use $\gcd(x,n)=1$. Consider $2^m \mod 10$ for example. Yes we do repeat congruence classes by the time $x=n-1$, but we need $x^m=1 \mod n$.

Comment: Why is it n+1 elements instead of n-1 elements $\{x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}\}$ since m is positive and m<n?

Comment: @Larrry Yes, I was leaving you two pieces of work to do. [1] Since none of the elements can be congruent to $0 \pmod{n}$, the set $S = \{1,x,\cdots, x^{(n-1)}\}$ must have a congruency class repeat [2] Since $x$ rel. prime to $n$, so is each element in the set $S$.  Further, if $c$ rel. prime to $n$ and $ac \equiv bc\pmod{n}$, then $a \equiv b\pmod{n}.$

Comment: @Mike See the above comment.